# why intellij complains to add a return to an unreachable statement

Tags: java, intellij-idea, exception

My IDE keeps complaining to add a "retrun" statement in hello() method after the catch block. Isn't that return statement unreachable? so why should i include that?

```
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         hello();
    }


    public static boolean hello() {

        try{
            hello2();
        } catch(SQLException e){
            handleException();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static String hello2() throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLException("");
    }

    public static void handleException(){
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Isn't that return statement unreachable?

According to the rules that the JLS specifies for determining that a statement is reachable, the `return false;` statement is reachable.  (Refer to [JLS 14.21](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) for the full details<sup>1</sup>.)

The rules do not take account of the behavior of a separate method. They make the assumption that any method call *may* return, no matter how the method is actually implemented.

The JLS's assumption is essential in the case where the method is in a separate compilation unit.  (Consider the case where the called method is changed and recompiled without recompiling the calling method.)

It is also essential in the case where the logic of the method is complicated.  There will be cases where it would be impossible for a compiler to be sure whether a method can terminate; c.f. the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).  It would be a bad thing for the "correctness" of a Java program to depend on the ability of the compiler determine if an arbitrary method call could return or not.  The simple solution (adopted by the JLS) is that the compiler should not even try to do that ... for the purposes of reachability checking.

---

<sup>1 - Note that the reachability rules are essentially the same as they were in the Java Language Specification First Edition.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

The compiler doesn't analyze the code of `hello2()` and `handleException()` when compiling `hello()`, so it doesn't know that these methods always throw an exception. Therefore it requires a `return` statement in `hello()`, since the code following the try-catch block is reachable as far as the compiler can tell.

If you change your method to directly throw exceptions instead of calling methods that throw exceptions, you won't need the return statement :

```
public static boolean hello() {
    try{
        throw new SQLException("");
    } catch(SQLException e){
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`try-catch` simply say try the the problem and do the solution to resolve it and move on to further code execution

```
 try{
            hello2(); // exception 
        } catch(SQLException e){ // may occur , handle here 
            handleException();
        }
       // normal execution from here 

        return false;
```

plus your `hello2()` throws the exception which is already handled by the `catch` block and so complier thinks all the possibilities like if `hello2()` may not throw the exception always(or compiler don't go into Netegrity and assume the method will return value , only if it's not clearly preditable due to dynamic bheaviour of code ), so it is asking for return statement for that case